# Laravel case insensitive routes

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-4, case-insensitive, laravel-routing

**How do I define a case insensitive (part of a) route?**

Example:

- Route::get('/{userId}/profile');
- http://domain.com/123/profile works fine.

Any use of uppercase in the fixed part of the route does not work:

- http://domain.com/123/Profile does not work
- http://domain.com/123/proFILE does not work

I understand how I can make parameters like {parameter} use a regex pattern using ->with(), but that does not help me with the fixed part of the route, like described above.

Comment: Strictly speaking, using a parameter and regex *could* help with your specific problem (turn profile into a dynamic param, specify that it must be the word 'profile' case insensitively) however I understand that's far from an ideal solution. Definite stop-gap measure though.

Comment: The fixed part couldn't be case insensitive but if it were a dynamic param you could have done it as you know that already.

Comment: did you try something like `Route::get('{userId}/{profile}','Controller@action')->where('profile','/profile/i');` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be solved by defining routes the following way:

```
Route::get('/{userId}/{profile}')->with('profile', '(?i)profile(?-i)');
```

Even smarter, define it as `pattern`, then it also becomes available in Route groups.

```
Route::pattern('profile', '(?i)profile(?-i)');
Route::get('/{userId}/{profile}');
```

Comment: nice. I like the pattern solution

Comment: This helped me just now. Thank you.

Comment: In the first example, did you mean `->where()` instead of `->with()`? `where` works by using a route regular expression, whereas in Laravel 5.3 `with` causes an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::with()`

Answer (score 0):

Adding patterns only works on one route at a time, if you want all routes to be case insensitive add this to your /app/filter.php file in the before section:

I wrote a gist which does this: https://gist.github.com/samthomson/f670f9735d200773e543

Edit your app/filters.php to check for uppercase characters in the route and redirect them to a converted route.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Apache you could also do this:

At this the top of your **vhost file** add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
```

and in your **.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I haven't tried the mentioned solutions, but just came to think about general conversion of the URL to lower case: Some routes may need mixed upper/lower case, for example when case sensitive parameters are passed along via the URL (e.g. certain hash types etc).