# Is it possible to use caps and small later mix for URL in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Here is an example (It's in Laravel 4)..
I want my url like this `http://example.com/home/SiteLocation` 
and in `routes.php` I defined `Route::get('home/SiteLocation','HomeController@Functionname');`

My point is,

1. Is it possible to use like this `SiteLocation` (lower case and upper case mix) as url ?
2. If yes, how to define function in controller for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use like this SiteLocation (lower case and upper
>   case mix) as url ?

Yes - it should just work, you shouldnt need to modify your code

> If yes, how to define function in controller for the same ?

Your function name in your controller can be anything you like - it doesnt need to correspond to the url. For example this would work:

```
Route::get('home/SiteLocation','HomeController@siteLocation');
```

as would this:

```
Route::get('home/SiteLocation','HomeController@SiteLocation');
```

and this:

```
Route::get('home/SiteLocation','HomeController@other');
```

Comment: I'm getting Controller method not found. for all the above cases , once i make it 
Route::get('home/sitelocation','HomeController@getSitelocation'); it works ..!

Comment: Post your controller code. The "URL" and the "function" in your controller are two different things and are not related

Comment: So you should be able to do `Route::get('home/SiteLocation','HomeController@getSitelocation');` - that should work

Comment: Same issue ...Controller method not found.
here is my code -
routes.php 
Route::get('home/SiteLocation', 'HomeController@getSitelocation');
and in homecntroller 
public function getSitelocation()
    {
        echo "hello!";
    }

Answer (score 0):

It’s always good practice to avoid using capital letters in your URLs.

## Here’s why:

1-If your website is on a Windows server, then www.example.com/about will be handled exactly the same as www.example.com/About.
  The Windows server is case insensitive.  If your website is hosted on Linux, then those two addresses will be seen as two different pages(You can also provide a regex instead - but this might be a little OTT.). 
2-Having Two URLs Lead to the Same Page is No Good for Search Rankings.

See [define a case insensitive (part of a) route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731151/laravel-case-insensitive-routes)

Comment: -1. Windows machines are only case sensitive for file names - not for URLs. Because Laravel routes all URLs through `index.php` - then they are treated as case sensitive. According to W3 standards - URLs are supposed to be case sensitive: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7996919/1317935

Comment: Also "Having Two URLs Lead to the Same Page is No Good for Search Rankings." is not relevant here. If the URL is case sensitive - then there is still only one URL to the path - so this doesnt apply.