# Laravel change uri to lowercase

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

You know Laravel is case sensitive.
How can I Forced user to used lowercase in address bar ?
can I change Uri in middleware ? how ?
I'm using Laravel 5.1.10

Comment: I think you might find you're answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964973/how-to-make-routes-in-laravel-case-insensitive

Comment: Specifically the not-accepted answer if you want to actually redirect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32012337/1551393 (though it looks like you *may* have to upgrade it to be a middleware).

Answer (score 0):

You can't force user to use lower or upper case in the address bar. But you want to keep this in mind. Is case sensitive or not case sensitive really depends on the server and its environment.

In general Windows machines are case insensitive on the other hand, Linux is case sensitive. Lowercase is the way to go or you will be chasing bugs like a dog chasing his tail.

Hope this help.