# Is Laravel routing case-sensitive?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I seem to receive a `Method Not Allowed` error when using the following cURL command:

```
curl -sv https://jwelford.co.uk/cart/add -X POST
```

However, when using `post` instead of `POST`, everything seems to work fine.

```
Route::post('/cart/add', function(Request $request){
    return 'You hit /cart/add';
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can check it here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964973/how-to-make-routes-in-laravel-case-insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964973/how-to-make-routes-in-laravel-case-insensitive)

Comment: This looks like it's for the URL its self.  Can I use something like this on the method as well?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is case-sensitive,
and you can make it case-insensitive

read this answer if you want to make laravel case-insensitive:

[How to make routes in Laravel case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964973/how-to-make-routes-in-laravel-case-insensitive)